# Android: How can I take a screenshot of the current activity and share it?

Tags: java, android, share, screenshot, android-external-storage

I should be able to press a button that takes a screenshot of the current activity (without showing the Toast message on the display) and then opens the dialog to share it on social networks or various apps. I hope you got what I need to do and you can help me.

Comment: Your Activity or Activity of the current app the user is looking at?

Comment: An Activity where a a score of a card game is shown. @DeeV

Answer (score 0):

[How to take a screenshot programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)

After that, you can send a [share intent](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) with the screen shot image uri attached.
Like so:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```